# css for styling button

Tags: css, button

I want to make my button responsive, so I can't use the image together with background. I can use the second picture of the cart only, but how can style it, so part of it remains outside?

[image]

[image]

Comment: it's a little unclear as to exactly what you want.  could you show your attempts and provide specific questions?

Comment: Show us some code. What have you already tried?

Comment: Do you have a copy of the shopping cart icon by itself, without the coloured background behind it?

The easiest approach would be to add the cart using generated content( e.g., ".btn::before{ }", but if not, then... well, this complicates matters.

Comment: If I use background: url("btn-cart.png") no-repeat left center #a8274c; the image remains inside the box, I want part of it to be outside as shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could apply the `background-image` to a :pseudo-element of a `button` element and position them using `top` and `left` properties.

```css
button {
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
  height: 35px;
  background: #B7004A;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
button:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 110%;
  top: -7px;
  left: -3px;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aiy4E.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: auto 105%;
}
```

```html
<button></button>
```

Comment: Generally that's the idea. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Is it something like this you are looking for?

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vgayjg9j/2/

EDIT: updated the jsFiddle. It now sticks out.

```
<button><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows-8-metro-style/512/shoping_cart.png" /></button>

button {
    width: 120px;
    height: 40px;
}
button img {
    height: 100%;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: The cart should be partially outside the colored box. That's the problem.

Comment: I'm trying to make it using css background property, but it should look that way

Answer (score 0):

From your question I think you want to button to fill the screen if it is on smaller devices?

Media queries is where you should start.

Also make sure you use % for the width of the button, for example if you want you button to fill the screen the css would look something like this:

```
button {
  width: 100%;
}
```

And if the image should not change then I would define the width of the image in pixels:

```
button img {
  width: 40px;
}
```

Comment: I am using % for the width, I just want to make the cart be partially outside the button.